# Bootstrap 3 Tabs Content Overflows Footer

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Stumped on why the tab content is overflowing the footer.  The issue isn't in the footer.  If you click the second tab with a ton of text it just overruns the footer.  I've tried to add clearing divs, but that doesn't seem to matter.

Here's an example:

http://themes.siiimple.com/newsgrid/test-tabs/

If you click the "Profile" tab, you'll see the example.  Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Did you fix it? I don't see where's the issue.

Comment: I think I've resolved the issue.  It was related to an equal heights script I was running on the single page.  I only figured it out when resizing the browser window - the height adjusted to the tab content.  There's probably a workaround to run the equal heights script as well, but not sure what that would be.  This is the equal heights script:  http://jsliang.github.com/eqHeight.coffee

Answer (score 0):

Issue was related to an equal height script that was not recognizing the height of the content in the tabs, until window resizing.  Here's the script that is conflicting.  http://jsliang.github.com/eqHeight.coffee